# Editing PDF before signing using DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi, oracle-service-cloud

We are using DocuSign Rest API to send the base64 version of the PDF document from Oracle Service Cloud Application for e-signature. We are using the embedded signature technique. In the form, there are few fields that we want users to fill in before they complete the signature. We have made these fields editable. When the document is viewed in the browser, all the fields are shown as editable. However, the same form when re-generated by DocuSign for signature, all the fields become read-only. We are not able to find any setting in the DocuSign account or parameter for DocuSign API which will allow embedded signers to edit the document before signing.

Answer (score 0):

Fields have a "Locked" property. You can set this to false to allow the fields to be edited e.g.

```
Text textField = new Text
        {
            DocumentId = "1",
            PageNumber = "1",
            XPosition = "15",
            YPosition = "15",
            Height = "14",
            Width = "50",
            Value = "",
            Locked = "false"
        };
```

This example is from the .NET MVC/Core API.